# Strange Apache/PHP&Perl behavior—error (70007)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, perl

I’m dealing with a particular strange situation: I have two Linux machines, one with Scientific Linux (v4.8) and one with CentOS (v6.2). On the SL machine I have a XAMPP distribution with Apache 2.2.9, while on the CentOS I have Apache 2.2.15 (no XAMPP). Both machines are on the same network.

Now, here is my situation: I have the exact same script on both machines—a combination of PHP, JavaScript, and Perl—that uploads files from the browser to the server. When I try to access the script on the SL machine, everything goes as expected, while the one on the CentOS behaves unexpected: from a particular network, that is behind a firewall and a proxy, when I’m trying to upload a small file, it works, but when I’m trying to upload a bigger file (60 MB), Apache logs the error below and it breaks.

```
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: Error reading request entity data, referer:
```

However, from different locations, both scripts behave as expected, without errors, even while trying to upload files as big as 500 MB.

I have no idea where to or what to look for. How can I fix this?

UPDATE: Monitoring the network with Firebug, I get

```
502 Proxy Error ( The specified network name is no longer available.  )
```

BUT, as I was saying, this doesn’t happen for the SL server, event if I access it through the same proxy. Why?!

UPDATE2: On the machine that works, the SL, I have a `Cache-Control: max-age=0`. Could this have anything to do with it?